# How can a group by be converted to a self-join

Tags: sql

for a table such as:

```
employeeID | groupCode
   1            red111
   2            red111
   3            blu123
   4            blu456
   5            red553
   6            blu423
   7            blu341
```

how can I count the number of employeeIDs that are in parent groups (such as red or blu, but there are many more groups in the real table) that have a total number of group members greater than 2 (so all those with blu in this particular example) excluding themselves.

To expand: groupCode consists of a parent group (three letters), followed by some numbers for the subgroup.

using a self-join, or at least without using a group by statement.

So far I have:

```
SELECT T1.employeeID
FROM TABLE T1, TABLE T2
WHERE T1.groupCode <> T2.groupCode
  AND SUBSTR(T1.groupCode, 1, 3) = SUBSTR(T2.gorupCode, 1, 3);
```

but that doesn't do much for me...

Comment: Since this is tagged as homework, you will need to show what you've attempted so far.  We're happy to help when you get stuck, but generally won't provide complete answers to homework questions.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `group by`. It looks like the perfect thing to use for this job.

Comment: because the teacher is an idiot and wants us to use an index to optimise the stupid query as he didn't think of using an aggregate query. We have to show that using an index will improve our query. My first thought was to use GROUP BY, but an index does not improve it, so I will not get full marks.

Comment: What would be the expected output with the data you have here?

Comment: I believe it is supposed to count employeeIDs of 3, 4, 6, 7 and so return the result of 4 as that is the number of employees who are in a group that has more than 2 other employees (excluding themselves). Yes, the wording of the question is terrible as well.

Comment: Why would it not be all returned results because RED also has count >= 2, do the numbers afterwards mean anything in the context of your task?

Comment: it is > 3 as you have to exclude the employee in question, and think of how many OTHER employees are in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an index on the first 3 characters of `EMPLOYEE`.

Then try this one:

```
SELECT ed.e3
     , COUNT(*) 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
  JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT                    
        SUBSTR(groupCode, 1, 3) AS e3
      FROM EMPLOYEE 
    ) ed
    ON e.groupCode LIKE CONCAT(ed.e3, '%')
GROUP BY ed.e3
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3           --- or whatever is wanted
```

Comment: I like this. I can't think of what else could be indexed that would be helpful in this case. Personally it feels very wrong to do this though, I would have thought that the design of the table should be changed to have the parent group and subgroup in separate columns. Or even better the subgroups being indexed in their own table along with a reference to their parent group... Homework exercises always annoy me like this. :)

Comment: Yes, splitting the column into two (group, subgroup) would definitely be better in any case. You can actually put my `(SELECT DISTINCT ...) ed` into a new (parentgroup) table and make another table for subgroup. And run the queries with normalized tables to show that it's better for performance (than this unnormalized situation where it's hard to even find an index - and make it work).

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT substring(empshirtno, 1, 3), 
      Count(SELECT 1 from myTable as myTable2 
            WHERE substring(mytable.empshirtno, 1, 3) = substring(mytable2.empshirtno, 1, 3))
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY substring(mytable2.empshirtno, 1, 3)
```

maybe counting from a subquery is speedier with an index

Comment: trying to figure out that in oracle sql as it says missing expression (just removed the AS to make it oracle-like.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't know was Oracle. This is a MS SQL expression. Does Oracle supports subquerys?

Comment: Also you use group by... I think you should be able to move the count into the subselect though and then just use a distinct on the outside to remove duplicates.

Comment: @chris: AFAIK you can't use COUNT without GROUP BY (unless you want to count the whole table). The homework is optimizing the query using indexes.

Comment: Ah, didn't read the comments talking about indexes. I just read the question itself. And in this case counting the whole table is fine since the inner query each time it is evaluated is only returning the rows that much the substring - effectively that group by is in the where clause of the inner query so becomes superfluous.